# How can I find if a custom field exist in org using apex?

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex

How can I find if a custom field(Sobject, Custom Setting/Metadata) exist in org using apex? I might have its partial name or similar sub string.

Comment: What do you mean by a partial name or sub string? How are you intending to use that to identify a field?

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a Dynamic Search, but... why do you want to have something like that? It is part of a requirement?

Comment: @David, If field name is "Total Price", Then I shall be able to find field if I input "Total" or "Price"@Carlos, this is not part of requirement but something helpful while working

Comment: a pure apex option would be to use the Schema.Describe methods and loop through all fields in the returned map, using regex matching

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best option, in my opinion, is to use [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en):

After it is installed, you can access the Salesforce Inspector by clicking on the silver blue background arrow on top right from inside a record and click on "Show all data"

[image]

Then you can use the search function:

[image]

On the Filter search start typing the name of the field.... and voila :) 
The only thing you need to make sure is that you are inside the object to access the fields of that particular object...